# Marbles counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

It is said that there are 4 red marbles, 4 blue marbles, and 8 yellow marbles. So the question is, that how many combinations are there taking all 16 marbles in a row.

Actually I did try to solve this problem, and I think the answer is

$$3^4 \cdot 2^4 $$

but I also think I get too small number to consider it correct. So that's why I decided to ask u guys

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.  BTW, does it say "combinations" or "permutations"?

Comment: are the red marbles indistinguishable from each other?  Suppose that you label the red marbles $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$.  Suppose that when you are identifying the $(16!)$ ways that the marbles are arranged, you only consider those arrangements where the 4 red marbles are in the 1st  four positions?  How many ways can this occur?  What is the relevance of my asking this question, with respect to the overall question?

Comment: @user2661923 yes the marbles are the same

Comment: "Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments."  Please show work directly in the question.

Comment: Can you reproduce the **exact** question you were given ?

Comment: @trueblueanil the exact question is how many distinct combinations are there of retrieving the marbles from the box

Comment: This can't be the **full** question. There is something about "taking all $16$ marbles in a row" If the part in quotes is true, it is not *combinations*, but *permutations* with multiple occurrences of three distinct types of elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you meant permutations.

There are $4$ red marbles, $4$ blue, and $8$ yellow.

The {$4$} red marbles are identical in all aspects, similarly the {$4$} blue and {$8$} yellow are identical too.

Total number of objects too be arranged: $4+4+8 = 16$

Ways to arrange $16$ objects (non-identical) : $16!$

And $3$ pairs of items are identical giving us:

$$\boxed{\cfrac{16!}{4!4!8!}}$$

Hope this helped.

Comment: yasss!! thanks a lot!!